# Correct PHP Code? - To Insert to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json, swift

I have an iOS app using Swift 3 using a PHP file to receive objects but now working to update objects into the database.

I'm new to PHP so my question is, is the php code below correct? It's supposed to insert a variable from my app which is +1 points from a button to go through php and UPDATE my 'tests' table in mysql database. I already have a column in the database called testPop and the variable is also called testPop which is received in a json object array but I'm just trying to update the table.

So if `row1 = id:1 testName:test1 testPop:0`

I want testPop to update its value every time someones adds a point +1

Current PHP Code:

```
<?php

$host = "host";
$db = "db";
$user = "user";
$pass = "pass";

$connection = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);

// Guessing: Posting into MySQL Object
$id = $_POST["id"];

// Checking if connection can be established
if(!$connection){
    die("Connection Failed");
}
else
{
    // Selecting Database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    // Check if it can connect to Database
    if(!$dbconnect){
        die("Unable to connect to Database");
    }
    else
    {
        $query = sprintf("UPDATE tests SET testPop=testPop+1 WHERE id = %d", $id);

        $resultset = mysql_query($query, $connection);

        echo "Successfully added";
        echo $query;
    }
}

?>
```

Swift 3 Code: Sending Data to database:

```
func sendData() {

    let postDataURL = "http://exampleip.com/Send.php"
    let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: postDataURL)!
    let request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(url:url as URL)

    let bodyData = String(1)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = bodyData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request as URLRequest, queue: OperationQueue.main)
    {
        (response, data, error) in
        print(response!)

        if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
            let statusCode = httpResponse.statusCode

            if statusCode==200 {
                print("Connection Successful")

            } else {
                print("Connection Failed (!200)")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

----- Added Additional Code for better understanding -----

New: MySQL Code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tests` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`testName` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`testPop` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=13 ;

INSERT INTO `tests` (`id`, `testName`, `testPop`) VALUES
(1, 'Test 1', '0'),
(2, 'Test 2', '0'),
(3, 'Test 3', '0'),
(4, 'Test 4', '0'),
(5, 'Test 5', '0'),
(6, 'Test 6', '0'),
(7, 'Test 7', '0'),
(8, 'Test 8', '0'),
(9, 'Test 9', '0'),
(10, 'Test 10', '0'),
(11, 'Test 11', '0'),
(12, 'Test 12', '0');
```

Example: On how I receive from the database, using json. Don't know if this helps. Swift 3

```
func retrieveData() {

let getDataURL = "http://exampleip.org/tests.php"
let url: NSURL = NSURL(string: getDataURL)!

do {

    let data: Data = try Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
    jsonArray = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! NSMutableArray

    // Looping through jsonArray
    for i in 0..<jsonArray.count {

        // Create Test Object
        let tID: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "id") as! String
        let tName: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "testName") as! String
        let tPop: String = (jsonArray[i] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "testPop") as! String

        // Add Test Objects to Test Array
        testArray.append(Test(testName: tName, andTestPop: tPop, andTestID: tID))

    }
}
catch {
    print("Error: (Retrieving Data)")
}

myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: what is `$_POST["a"]` supposed to be equal to?

Comment: If you're writing new code, **_please_ don't use the `mysql_*` functions**. They are old and broken, were deprecated in PHP 5.5 (which is so old it no longer even receives security updates), and completely removed in PHP 7. Additionally, your code is wide open to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Use [`PDO`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [`mysqli_*`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) with _prepared statements_ and _parameter binding_ instead. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/354577 for details.

Comment: @bugfroggy thats for when I was using INSERT INTO VALUES not UPDATE

Comment: @Chris Thanks! Was that the only errors in the code? Changing the mysql_* functions to mysqli?

Comment: Your code is incorrect then because you're using it in your `UPDATE` query: `$testPop = $_POST["a"]; $query = "UPDATE tests SET testPop='$testPop' WHERE $testPop";`

Comment: @BroSimple You should change your queries to be prepared statements as well rather than just literally appending an `i` to all of your `mysql_*` functions. While it would work, it's not recommended.

Comment: Whats the correct way of going by this?

Comment: @BroSimple Going about what, exactly? I'm not sure what you want to update and in what scenario. Do you want when a page is loaded for something to be updated in a database? Which value in which row do you want to be updated?

Comment: FYI - nothing about this question is specific to iOS or Swift. It applies to any client.

Comment: @bugfroggy I have another question open explaining the iOS part but I made this one because I thought I had to fix the php code first then move to something else. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956595/php-swift-receiving-object-add-1-send-it-back-to-database?noredirect=1#comment69122748_40956595

Comment: @rmaddy I thought I had to go through to the php first but I have another question with the swift side code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40956595/php-swift-receiving-object-add-1-send-it-back-to-database?noredirect=1#comment69122748_40956595

Comment: @BroSimple but when this script is run, you want it to update something in a database. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes thats correct

Comment: that `$testPop` is that a string? and where's the form for this?

Comment: and this `WHERE $testPop` how is that supposed to end as? seems unfinished to me. anyhow, somebody "popped" an answer below, ask them.

Comment: Yes in my ios app, its received as a string, what do you mean with form, the mysql code?

Comment: @BroSimple Okay. And you want which value(s) to be updated? What conditions must they meet in your `WHERE` statement?

Comment: The testPop should be updated with an increment of +1

Comment: But do you only have one row? Which row(s) do you want it updated on? All of them?

Comment: @bugfroggy i have several rows like 50+ objects, in my swift app the user clicks the button on which row they want to add +1

Comment: In that case you need your app to send a parameter to your PHP script with the row ID you want to be updated. Your MySQL query will look something like `UPDATE \`tests\` SET \`testPop\`='$testPop' WHERE \`id\`='$rowID'`. You should also convert this and the rest of your script to use the latest MySQLi techniques: [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi Overview](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php). Other than that your script looks fine to me.

Comment: @bugfroggy thank you I will try this. Also normally in my app I use indexPath.row to get the specific row? Does that change anything?

Comment: I don't know how to code in iOS or what the goal of your application is so this question would be better for someone who does know. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$query = sprintf("UPDATE tests SET testPop=testPop+1 WHERE id = %d", $id);
```

- First, if you're incrementing a value, let the database do it for you. This will prevent a race condition: if/when 2 queries happen simultaneously, only one will be saved properly.
- Second, don't add user-generated input directly into a query without escaping. Using sprintf with %d forces the id variable to an integer.

Comment: How is this code? $query = sprintf("UPDATE tests SET testPop=$testPop+1 WHERE id = $id"); - Its the same except I changed it to  $testPop or do I do it your way?

Comment: @BroSimple Since I don't know your application, I cannot tell you exactly what to do. But, your example still uses un-escaped user input. If you don't care about a race-condition and we assume testPop is an integer, you can do `$query = sprintf("UPDATE tests SET testPop=%d+1 WHERE id = %d", $testPop, $id);`

Comment: With the code I have, the database is not being updated. - I added additional code to the question, maybe you'll get a better understanding. Also updated the php code and sendData code.

Comment: Since you're +1'ing a test, my original answer seems to be the best. `$query = sprintf("UPDATE tests SET testPop=testPop+1 WHERE id = %d", $id);` That way, if testPop was 4, it is now 5.

Comment: Okay thanks trying this code but is the swift code for sending data to database, is it correct? How would I know the php code worked?